# Powershell array of arrays loop process

Tags: powershell, foreach

I need help with loop processing an array of arrays.  I have finally figured out how to do it, and I am doing it as such...

```
$serverList = $1Servers,$2Servers,$3Servers,$4Servers,$5Servers

$serverList | % {
    % {
        Write-Host $_
        }
    }
```

I can't get it to process correctly.  What I'd like to do is create a CSV from each array, and title the lists accordingly.  So 1Servers.csv, 2Servers.csv, etc...  The thing I can not figure out is how to get the original array name into the filename.  Is there a variable that holds the list object name that can be accessed within the loop?  Do I need to just do a separate single loop for each list?

Comment: Note that after you've done `$serverList = $1Servers,$2Servers,$3Servers,$4Servers,$5Servers` the list of variable *names* is lost. You only have variable *values* in `$serverList` now.

Comment: Yes I met this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try :

```
$1Servers = "Mach1","Mach2"
$2Servers = "Mach3","Mach4"
$serverList = $1Servers,$2Servers
$serverList | % {$i=0}{$i+=1;$_ | % {New-Object -Property @{"Name"=$_} -TypeName PsCustomObject} |Export-Csv "c:\temp\$($i)Servers.csv" -NoTypeInformation }
```

I take each list, and create new objects that I export in a CSV file. The way I create the file name is not so nice, I don't take the var name I just recreate it, so if your list is not sorted it will not work.

It would perhaps be more efficient if you store your servers in a hash table :

```
$1Servers = @{Name="1Servers"; Computers="Mach1","Mach2"}
$2Servers = @{Name="2Servers"; Computers="Mach3","Mach4"}
$serverList = $1Servers,$2Servers
$serverList | % {$name=$_.name;$_.computers | % {New-Object -Property @{"Name"=$_} -TypeName PsCustomObject} |Export-Csv "c:\temp\$($name).csv" -NoTypeInformation }
```

Answer (score 1):

Much like JPBlanc's answer, I kinda have to kludge the filename... (FWIW, I can't see how you can get that out of the array itself).

I did this example w/ `foreach` instead of `foreach-object` (`%`).  Since you have actual variable names you can address w/ `foreach`, it seems a little cleaner, if nothing else, and hopefully a little easier to read/maintain:

```
$1Servers = "apple.contoso.com","orange.contoso.com"
$2Servers = "peach.contoso.com","cherry.contoso.com"
$serverList = $1Servers,$2Servers
$counter = 1

foreach ( $list in $serverList ) {
    $fileName = "{0}Servers.csv" -f $counter++
    "FileName: $fileName"
    foreach ( $server in $list ) {
        "-- ServerName: $server"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue myself.  Because I wasn't able to get the object name through, I just changed the nature of the object.  So now my server lists consist of two columns, one of which is the name of the list itself.

So...

```
$1Servers = += [pscustomobject] @{
        Servername = $entry.Servername
        Domain = $entry.Domain
        }
```

Then...

```
$serverList = $usaServers,$devsubServers,$wtencServers,$wtenclvServers,$pcidevServers
```

Then I am able to use that second column to name the lists within my foreach loop.